# Why isn't Euler's theorem working to find the smallest $k$ such that $10^k \equiv 1 \pmod {\!9}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$10^k \equiv 1 \pmod {\!9}$

According to [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) and the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), smallest $k$ is $\phi(9) = 6$, but clearly the smallest $k$ is $k=1$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Both $\lambda(n)$ (Carmichael function) and $\phi(n)$ work like $f$ here: $(a,n)=1\,\Rightarrow\,a^{f(n)}\equiv 1\pmod{\! n}$, except that $\lambda(n)$ may be smaller (it is defined as the smallest $f(n)$ that satisfies this statement). The smallest $k$ in your question is called the _order_, denoted $\text{ord}_9 10$, and $\lambda(n),\phi(n)$ don't talk about it. It is easy to prove that the order divides any $l$ such that $a^{l}\equiv 1\pmod{\! n}$, i.e. $\text{ord}_{9}10\mid l$ (assume not-then $l=h(\text{ord}_n a)+r$ with $0<r<\text{ord}_n a$ and $a^l\equiv a^r\equiv 1\pmod{\!n}$, contr).

Comment: So in particular $\text{ord}_n a\mid \phi(n),\lambda(n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Euler Theorem doesn't say anything about the smallest $k$, it only says that it holds for $\varphi(m)$ where $m$ is the modulus.

Answer (score 1):

The smallest solution is a divisor of $\varphi(n)$.

Note that the Carmichael Function gives the smallest solution of $a^k\equiv 1\pmod n$ that works for all $a$ coprime with $n$.

So it stands to reason that the Carmichael function for $n = 9$ won't be $1$ since, for instance, taking $a = 2$ we get $2^1 \not\equiv 1 \pmod 9$.

The equation you have is a special case. Note that $10 = 9+1$ so

$$10^k = (9+1)^k = 9^k + {k\choose 1}9^{k-1} + \ldots + {k\choose k-1}9 + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod 9$$

So any $k$ is a solution. Generally the smallest solution for $(a+1)^k \equiv 1 \pmod a$ is $k=1$ for any positive integer $a$.

Answer (score 0):

You have written the theorem for a specific value, $10$. Euler's theorem is uniformly for all $a$ with $\gcd(a,n)=1$, then $a^{\varphi(n)}\equiv1\pmod n$.